# MFC Open Images and Show in a Picture Control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Can someone help me to show images at the runtime in a Picture Control. What I want to do is open an image  (.bmp , .jpg ,.png etc) using an Open Dialog and show it in a picture control. Nice tutorial is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Spend some time looking for existing solutions. You'll most likely end up with GDI or GDI+

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24969/An-MFC-picture-control-to-dynamically-show-picture